# flutter FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Creation failed)

Tags: flutter

```dart
  static Future<String> init() async {

    var installPath = "/Users/purplecity/code/likai_flutter/beiwanglu";
    Directory notePath = Directory("${installPath}/NoteStorage/");
    var noteDir = await notePath.exists();
    if (!noteDir) {
      await notePath.create();
    }
```

at Flutter Device:ios emulator it is ok. but at Device:Android-x86 emulator it has error

what i need do? i dont want use asset.. just read local file...

```
Error:

FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = '/Users/purplecity/Library/Android/sdk/NoteStorage/' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Which Android version you tested the app on and this `/Users/purplecity/code/likai_flutter/beiwanglu` is not a valid path for storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter allows you to place in Assets (json included etc.) to your app. You doing this manually may be causing this issue.

Try the following in your pubspec.yaml

```
  flutter:
   assets:
     - NoteStorage/
```

**Make sure the identation is perfect, pubspec.yaml is very touchy about that.**

Then you can load the asset using this:

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

Future<String> loadAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/NoteStorage/b1.json');
}
```

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

Comment: thank u!   i try to write a note app.  and i storage note  text use json format file. so if i add a new note then need create a new json file. it will create at  NoteStorage/ ?

Comment: I don't think that will work with assets as they are virtual. The path doesnt really exist.  In your case I'd take a look at this: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Comment: If the 'Creation failed' happens again, you probably need more permissions on Android.